# .NET Core MVC view components in desktop app: Component.InvokeAsync can't find view

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, razor, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I've built a website in ASP.NET Core, and it works fine.

Now I'm trying to launch my ASP.NET Core Web App inside a Windows Chromium Desktop App, following the instructions [here](https://docs.servicestack.net/netcore-windows-desktop#launch-net-core-app-inside-a-windows-chromium-desktop-app).

I run `app MyMvcApp.dll`. The app launches, but attempts to load a view for a view component (`ProgressViewComponent`), and throws the error:

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Components/Progress/Default' was not found. The following locations were searched:
> /Views/RawDataFileCopy/Components/Progress/Default.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Components/Progress/Default.cshtml
> /Pages/Shared/Components/Progress/Default.cshtml

The line that failed:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Progress", new { processId = Model.ProcessId, processName = Model.ProcessName })
```

In Visual Studio, in my ASP.NET Core project, I have the file at:

```
Views/Shared/Components/Progress/Default.cshtml
```

This works fine when I run the web app in a browser.

Interestingly, I've noticed that the compiler creates `MyMvcApp.Views.dll`, but if I decompile it I can't actually see the `Progress/Default` view, so maybe the problem is that it's not compiling the view correctly?

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The build action on the view wasn't set to *Content*.  I changed it to *Content*, and it worked.